# Flagging / editing mildly offensive posts

Tags: discussion

The first answer to [*Why is my car hard to start only after a few hours?*](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/40657/why-is-my-car-hard-to-start-only-after-a-few-hours) starts off with:

> ND (DENSO) spark plugs Suh HUH HUCK & NGK is great.

To my eye that's unnecessarily crude and lacks backup… But, on the other hand, there are no spark plugs in my world these days and maybe ND plugs aren't all that great… So as I was trying to clean up the answer, I was torn about what to do. The options seemed to be:

- Flag the post as offensive.
- Convert the statement into a more polite one "I don't like ND plugs, I think NGK makes better ones."
- Delete the comment all together, or
- Ask the OP to back up the assertion.

I ended up deciding on the last option since it kept the others open and didn't ask one of the moderators to take over the problem. But I'm wondering, what's the best practice here?

Answer (score 4):

To be forthright with you on this, I think you took a good approach. Realistically you could have taken any approach to it and I would have been good all around, but I usually jump the gun on such things, so there you go.

Really though, use your best judgement in such circumstances.

- If you find a comment over the top, doesn't adhere to the "be nice" policy of SE, or is just rather rude/crude ... edit away. Do not have a fear of this. I cannot imagine anyone on the site having issue with it.
- If you wonder if something is borderline, post it up in the chat and get a feel for what anyone else feels may need to be done with it. Keeping it in the open and getting a site consensus is never a bad thing.
- If you are still unsure, flag it. Either myself, Bob, or Ducati can take it from there. I don't think any of us has any issue taking care of such issues.

I hope this helps.